# $.ajax sends null parameters to wcf in IE

Tags: c#, wcf, json, internet-explorer, ntlm

I have the interface below that defines my WCF services.  Sometimes the 'parameters' parameter has been null when this is called.  Other times it is not.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContactRelationshipManager
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  void SaveActivityLogEntry(SaveActivityLogEntryParameters parameters);
}
```

Here is my behaviors section in the app.config (I'm running this as a windows service)

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ContactRelationshipManagerBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Here is my javascript call:

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: serviceCallUrl,
  data: JSON.stringify(params),
  success: callbackHandler
});
```

The result of `JSON.stringify(params)` is

"{"parameters":{"ContactEmailAddress":"blah@gmail.com","LiasonsForContact":[25],"ActivityLogEntry":{"Date":"/Date(1316634966273)/","LiasonFK":25,"TypeFK":1,"MethodFK":3,"Description":"tt","ContactFK":32}}}"

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here in practice?  This works fine all the time in chrome and firefox.  I also just tested this with Fiddler while debugging the service and the parameter came back null with Fiddler closed and NOT null when Fiddler is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up playing with a bunch of different techniques to get it to work including taking a stream as my function parameter and serializing it inside the function with JSON.NET.  That didn't work either.  I finally found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328229/under-iis6-post-data-method-arguments-in-jquery-ajax-post-to-wcf-service-is-nu) which led me to believe that it was an NTLM problem.  My website uses windows authentication in IIS7 and it calls a WCF service hosted as a windows service.  On the server side I changed the security on my webHttpBinding to be as such:

```
<binding name="webBinding">
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
      realm="" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

After doing this everything works fine in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Fiddler, for example, to sniff what's actually being sent? I normally pass a data object directly to `$.ajax` and let it handle serializing the object. I have a guess that the stringified JSON is being encoded inappropriately.

Comment: The problem is that if I use Fiddler then my WCF service receives the parameter correctly.  I can't use Fiddler to test because it's impacting the result.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have not had any problems, you have all the required configurations except your missing a few properties in your ajax call. I don't know if this might help.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
dataType: "json"
processData: false
```